# my javascript for loading external css files isn't working. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, css

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype)
{
if (filetype=="css") 
 {
    var fileref = document.createElement("link");
    fileref.rel = "stylesheet";
    fileref.type = "text/css";
    fileref.href = "filename";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
 }
}
loadjscssfile("cssgreen.css", "css")
```

and in my html I have

```
<a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('cssgreen.css','css')">Load green</a>
```

is there an issue in the html or the js, im fairly new to this so i could be making some mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `"filename"` to `filename`. You are sending a hardcoded string as an argument instead of the parameter passed into the function.

Comment: i did the change but now its loading `cssgreen.css` instead of `cssred.css` and won't load `cssred.css`

Comment: `<a href="javascript:loadjscssfile('cssred.css','css')">Load red</a>` would load `cssred.css`, provided it is in the same directory as `cssgreen.css`.

Comment: DUH im so dumb i forgot to change that thnx

Answer (score 0):

try removing the quotes around "filename" since it's a variable and not a quoted string;

`fileref.href = filename;`